# Cannot Launch Activity but No Errors Appear[AlarmReminder]

Tags: java, android, android-intent, gradle

I recently was studying making an AlarmReminder on youtube by this man's tutorial videos: DelaroyStudios.

Anyway... I followed his tutorial and made it work on a separate app. So next I modified it to the way I want my alarmreminder to be and tried to add it to my activity, however when I click the button routing to its activity launcher, it won't go off. By the way here's the repo: https://github.com/delaroy/AlarmReminder

I tried debugging but I can't see errors, so I really don't know where to start in fixing this part. But I suspect its on the dependencies on the gradle perhaps? or some other factor? Anyway please take a look at my code where I suspect the problem might be coming from.

Here's the manifests:

**My Manifest**

```
<application
    android:name=".FireApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="com.loginpack.splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.loginpack.LoginActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.Welcome.Welcome" />
    <activity android:name="com.Welcome.CalendarActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.Welcome.Video" />
    <activity android:name=".Profile" />
    <activity android:name="com.Welcome.Image">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity android:name="com.alarmreminder.MainReminder">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.alarmreminder.AddReminderActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_add_reminder"
        android:parentActivityName="com.alarmreminder.MainReminder"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.alarmreminder.MainReminder"
            />
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.Welcome.Info" />
    <activity android:name=".Profile2" />
    <activity android:name=".Profile3"/>
```

I checked the code and I suspect nothing except for some deprecated codes that were usually couldn't have affected the overall performance of the activity to the point that it can't even be opened and debugged. Please help me find a way to make this work. or perhaps if you know any method for me to debug activities without any errors showing. Oh and by the way this is what shows in the **Verbose** when I click on the activity.

Here's the code of the Activity mentioned:

```
public class MainReminder extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private FloatingActionButton mAddReminderButton;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    AlarmCursorAdapter mCursorAdapter;
    AlarmReminderDbHelper alarmReminderDbHelper = new AlarmReminderDbHelper(this);
    ListView reminderListView;

    private static final int VEHICLE_LOADER = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainalarm);

        mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        mToolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);


        reminderListView = findViewById(R.id.list);
        View emptyView = findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        reminderListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);

        mCursorAdapter = new AlarmCursorAdapter(this, null);
        reminderListView.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);

        reminderListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainReminder.this, AddReminderActivity.class);

                Uri currentVehicleUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.CONTENT_URI, id);

                // Set the URI on the data field of the intent
                intent.setData(currentVehicleUri);

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });


        mAddReminderButton = findViewById(R.id.fab);

        mAddReminderButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), AddReminderActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(VEHICLE_LOADER, null, this);


    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        String[] projection = {
                AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry._ID,
                AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_TITLE,
                AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_DATE,
                AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_TIME,
                AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_REPEAT,
                AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_REPEAT_NO,
                AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_REPEAT_TYPE,
                AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_ACTIVE

        };

        return new CursorLoader(this,   // Parent activity context
                AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.CONTENT_URI,   // Provider content URI to query
                projection,             // Columns to include in the resulting Cursor
                null,                   // No selection clause
                null,                   // No selection arguments
                null);                  // Default sort order

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);

    }
}
```

[image]

PS: In the my manifest I didn't make it as the main launcher, since its only an activity after all.

Comment: It's unlikely that the problem is in the gradle file. Aside from your manifest, the important stuff is your Java code. You'll need to provide a [mcve] in the question. Please don't link to necessary information offsite. Also, we don't need to see the working example you're following, so you can omit all that.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks, I edited it a bit now, at least I know its not from the gradle, a step forward, I could narrow my search for the problem, been up to it for hours right now. Sorry for putting up the working one,  I thought you guys might want to compare it, especially when I thought it was because of the dependencies.

Comment: OK, what specifically isn't working? Do you mean `AddReminderActivity` doesn't start when you click the `FloatingActionButton`? Aside from that, for the moment, you could really help yourself out by cleaning up a little, cut down on some possible confusion. Do you really have, like, half a dozen different packages going on in your project? That is, your app's package name is `com.example.espina.momshie`, by you've also got `com.loginpack`, `com.Welcome`, `com.alarmreminder`, etc., in that manifest. If those actually exist, you might want to move what you can to under your app's package.

Comment: ohhhh, alright! I'll try it out sir, thanks!  Whats not working is the launcher itself. Supposed to be when I click the a button it has to show the MainReminder, which is the launcher, so the apps supposed to go to that area. However, when I press the button nothing happens.

Comment: Oh, you mean from the home screen? Well, you have the launching `<intent-filter>` on the `com.loginpack.splash` `<activity>`. Does `com.loginpack.splash` actually point to an `Activity`? If not, that would be why nothing happens. If `MainReminder` is supposed to be your startup `Activity`, move that whole `<intent-filter>` there; the one with `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />` and `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`.

Comment: i mean.. sorry I misinputted it, what I meant was it was its launcher for its own activity. The splash screen is the launcher of the whole app, if I would put it in my terms.... so I wanted to press the button inside the app that supposed to navigate to the Scheduler part, however whenever I click, nothing happens, no errors either. I already did what you said and put it in one directory, still no good.

Comment: Now, it redirects to my home page. I don't know why.... but at least something had happened

Comment: OK, then we'd have to see the splash `Activity`, if you mean that's where the `Button` is to open `MainReminder`. Another tip to cut down on some of this confusion is that package names should be all lowercase letters – like you do have for `com.loginpack` – and the actual classes start with uppercase letters – e.g., `Splash` – so your launcher `Activity` should be `com.loginpack.Splash`. You don't really have to bother with renaming all that right now, though.

Comment: already did... no luck. thanks for the tip though, it's much cleaner now. but still pulling hairs out of this problem

Comment: Well, without seeing the code for the `Button` that's supposed to go to `MainReminder`, about all I can tell you is that it should look just like the `mAddReminderButton.setOnClickListener()` code you have above, except it should be `MainReminder.class` instead of `AddReminderActivity.class`.

Comment: Here it is sir: http://prntscr.com/ijt3lp I just took a screenshot since coding on comments could be messy. Also I tried changing build tools already to 25 just like the working one. Still no good...  :(

Comment: Oh, it's in a navigation drawer? Do the other items work? Or can you not click on any of them?

Comment: I can click at everything and goes to their activities quickly except with that one. I tried moving it to other parts of the drawer but no effect.

Comment: Uhh, hmm. I'm not sure what's happening, then. Are you really sure you're not getting any errors in the logcat? What's the `package` at the top of the `MainReminder` class file? Does it match what you currently have in the manifest for it? What happens if you comment out the `AlarmReminderDbHelper alarmReminderDbHelper = ...` line in `MainReminder`? That really shouldn't be instantiated there anyway. What happens, actually, if you comment out everything in `onCreate()` except the `super.onCreate()` and `setContentView()` lines?

Comment: FINALLY! I Caught up with something, by commenting and uncommenting the contents of onCreate() I was able to detect some bugs! For the app were those two unneeded toolbars! THANK YOU SO MUCH. I can sleep peacefully now. :)

Comment: No problem. That means, though, that you really should be seeing a stack trace for that Exception in your logcat. When you get back to your project, you might spend some time to figure out why you weren't seeing that. Maybe you've got a filter set? Anyhoo, glad you got it figured out. Cheers!